# django-admin is showing error ,How can i fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

When I run this command to create django project but it error, How can I fix it.

```
C:\Users\pawat\Documents\madpro\testapp>django-admin startproject name .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\pawat\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\pawat\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pawat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\pawat\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\pawat\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\pawat\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "c:\users\pawat\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\pawat\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\startproject.py", line 21, in handle
    super().handle('project', project_name, target, **options)
  File "c:\users\pawat\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\templates.py", line 160, in handle
    with open(new_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\pawat\\Documents\\madpro\\testapp\\manage.py'
```

Comment: What is the ```.``` at the end ? -> ```django-admin startproject name .```

Comment: You are in wrong directory. And why you give full stop after name ???